# Is there a function to convert hex color code text to a square in CSS with that color?

Tags: jquery

I need to convert a bunch of text with hex color code (eg `#fff`) into squares/thumbs with that color (a div with a CSS style).

Is there a jQuery function (or similar) to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You will need to write the code to achieve it, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an ready to use function in jQuery for that task, but it is simple to archive something like you described with the tools provided by jQuery:

```js
function createColorSquares(colors) {
  for (let color of colors) {
    let square = $('<span>', { class: 'colorSquare' }).css('background-color', color);
    $('body').append(square);
  }
}

let myColors = ['#f00', '#ff0', '#f0f', '#0ff'];
createColorSquares(myColors);
```

```css
.colorSquare {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```